# loadXML converting apos to '

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem with loadXML in PHP. For some reason the `&apos;` string in my XML gets converted to `'`. I do not want this. I'm adding a few things to the XML before saving it and I need it to (aside from what I add) maintain its original form. How do I turn off this automatic conversion?

Comment: I simply need to save the xml in a db but I need to inject a few things before I store it.

Comment: It has to be saved in the original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That encoding means that the original input was an unescaped apostrophe which was escaped not to break the XML.

If you want to, you can re-encode it again using `htmlspecialchars` after you read the value from the XML file.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Yip I'm gonna go down this route. Thanks GolezTrol.

Answer (score 1):

Unless its original form is [canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) - *which it isn't since `&apos;` does not appear in canonical XML* - there is no way to guarantee that your resulting output matches the original form.

There are many otherwise equivalent XML serializations of a document. In addition to dealing with character entity references such `&apos;` there is no way to ensure:

1. Attributes appear in the same order.
2. Attribute quote style is maintained.
3. That empty elements are represented the same. e.g. `<element/>` vs. `<element></element>`.
4. The XML declaration remains the same.
5. ... and so on.

Even if you could work around `&apos;` being serialized out as `'` by passing it through `htmlspecialchars()` without somehow destroying the rest of your XML, you suddenly wouldn't match up when the source has `&#039;` or `'` or a mix thereof.

If your input XML is not canonical, there simply is no going back. The information is not preserved.

---

If you do manage to start getting canonical XML as input, you can make sure your output matches up by using [`C14N()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php) in place of `saveXML()` when serializing the DOM out as an XML string.